# Laravel 5 css: link only the image not the full width of the column

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, sass

I have a div with some images centered inside with a link. The problem is that the link take the whole width of the column instead of just the image. Maybe because I used a margin auto? How can I solve it? Thanks.

SASS:

```
.anuncio{
    padding-bottom: 25px;

    img{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="anuncio">

    <a href="#">{!! HTML::image('images/one.png', '', array('width' => '180')) !!}</a>

    <a href="#">{!! HTML::image('images/two.svg', '', array('width' => '240')) !!}</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using **align-items** and **justify-content** in the css and **divs** for each element in the view.

SASS:

```
.anuncio{
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    img{
      padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="anuncio">

    <div><a href="#">{!! HTML::image('images/one.png', '', array('width' => '180')) !!}</a></div>

    <div><a href="#">{!! HTML::image('images/two.svg', '', array('width' => '240')) !!}</a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
.anuncio{
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    a{
       padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
    img{
      display: block;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This give me the same result, Shreyansh Panchal. Thanks.